# SQL Sumation from Different Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I would like some help on this matter.

I Have three tables.

Products Table,
Invoice Table,
Cash Table

Products Table has 2 Columns as follows (PID,BRAND)

Invoice Table has 2 columns as follows (PID,TOTALSALES)

Cash Table has 2 columns as follows (PID,TOTALSALES)

The PID's could have many different BRANDS.

for eg:

```
PID   BRAND
1     TEST1
2     TEST2
3     TEST3
```

All the three tables are linked by the PID column.

i have many rows in the invoice and cash tables.

My problem is to Group the SUMMED values of the TOTALSALES in the INVOICE and CASH tables BRAND wise.

I tried using left joins but the summation value always increases when there are more than 2 table in the join.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide us with some sample data and desired result ?

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: I guess the PK on PID is in Brand table. Is it?

Comment: @BartoszSiemasz as far as I understand there is no Brand table, PID is not unique.

Comment: Yes, my bad, there is Product table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` and then aggregate the results from the two tables together:

```
select p.brand, sum(invoice_sales) as invoice_sales, sum(cash_sales) as cash_sales
from ((select pid, totalsales as invoice_sales, 0 as cash_sales
       from invoice i
      ) union all
      (select pid, 0, totalsales
       from cash c
      )
     ) ic join
     product p
     on ic.pid = p.id
group by p.brand;
```

Answer (score 1):

summarise the data in the Invoice and Cash tables separately

```
 SELECT
    pr.BRAND, (ISNULL(Inv.TOTALSALES, 0.00) + ISNULL(Csh.TOTALSALES, 0.00)) TotalSales
FROM Products pr
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        PID, SUM(TOTALSALES) TOTALSALES
    FROM Invoice GROUP BY PID
) Inv ON Inv.PID = pr.PID
LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT
        PID, SUM(TOTALSALES) TOTALSALES
    FROM Cash GROUP BY PID
) Csh ON Csh.PID = pr.PID
ORDER BY pr.BRAND
```

Comment: Hi Ian, i would like both the summations of Invoice and Cash to be in one column only and not 2 separate columns. I also would like only 2 columns to be visible i.e. Brand and TotalSales.

Comment: amended to reflect your requirement  :)
I'd have a look on youtube for some starter videos on SQL.. there are lots

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate sums for the results of joining the tables by PID values and you will need to group the records by BRAND

```
select sum(Invoice.TOTALSALES) as invoice_sales, sum(Cash.TOTALSALES) as cash_sales
from Products
join Invoice
on Products.PID = Invoice.PID
join Cash
on Products.PID = Cash.PID
group by Invoice.PID, Products.BRAND;
```

If you do not need to group by products, then just omit Invoice.PID from the group by.

Answer (score 0):

another way to do it is by using subquerys

```
select p.*,
       (select sum(i.TOTALSALES) from Invoice i where i.PID = p.PID) as TotalSalesInvoice,
       (select sum(c.TOTALSALES) from Cash c where c.PID = p.PID) as TotalSalesCash
from   Products p
```